# GPSD - How to create a virtual GPS Source with lat/lon as input

Tags: python, c, nmea, gpsd

I have a system that uses gpsd as a source for positioning. I need to integrate it with another system that gives me latitude, longitude & time.

I was able to generate NMEA sentences using nmealib:

```
user@locahost :~/Desktop/nmealib$ build/samples_generate 
$GPGGA,154400.00,5000.0000,N,3600.0000,E,3,01,0.0,10.9,M,0.0,M,0.0,0000*7d
$GPGSA,A,3,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0.0,0.0,0.0*32
$GPGSV,1,1,01,00,00,000,00,00,00,000,00,00,00,000,00,00,00,000,00*78
```

My goal was then to pipe this to gpsd.

Option 1: with a FIFO file:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mkfifo    
gpsd /tmp/mkfifo    
./samples_generate > /tmp/mkfifo
```

Option 2: with a TCP socket:

```
gpsd tcp://localhost:8888
/samples_generate | nc -p 8888
```

On both situation, gpsd gave an error.

In essence, I would like to have similar functionality to gpsfake, but without using a logfile, instead using the stdout from my script.

Do you have any idea on how to realise this setup?

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to pipe the data:

```
stdbuf -oL build/samples_generate | gpsd -n -N /dev/stdin
```

- *stdbuf -oL* makes output of samples_generate line buffered, otherwise the text could be buffered and written in large chunks instead of line per line

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.

[GPSMON log of the working setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNfQ4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I only want to add more to the correct answer .

If you happen to own a WWAN modem card then do the following.

save the following lines  in file as a shell script and make it executable. let say it's named *wwan-gps.sh* . Please use the command *mmcli --list-modems* to know the modem index number. Here the index is zero (look at *mmcli -m 0* in the script)

```
while true; do
clear
mmcli -m 0 --location-get | tail -n +2|  sed 's#.*\$#$#'
sleep 2
done;
```

then run the following command as root from the same current directory as *wwan-gps.sh* :

```
stdbuf -oL ./wwan-gps.sh | gpsd -n -N -D 5 /dev/stdin
```

Also, if you you are one of those who use the sky map program kstars, this MUST help you. in the devices section of kstars , look for GPSD and make sure that you install the indi drivers